# How to calculate BMI using given input data in Python3.7

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to calculate a user's BMI from data that they input, (Height, Weight). I did the below code to try to calculate, but am currently getting the error code, "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'"

```
userHeight=input("Please enter your height in m.cm format")
userWeight=input("Please enter your weight in KG")
userBmi= input(userWeight/(userHeight*2))
```

I would like it that after the successful calculations that the BMI would be printed and rounded off to x.xx decimal places.

Comment: You might want to read on python basics at this point. without that you will just constantly hit the wall and it will become frustrating to you to continue.

Comment: It looks like you lack basic understanding of python, and Input/output Commands, I would suggest you to pick up a good book and read a bit before attempting this, or else you will constantly run into problems and programming will become difficult and frustrating for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few comments to be made, but most important is that you read a string from input(), and you need to parse it to float before doing calculations.

```
print("Please enter your height in m.cm format")
userHeight=float(input())
print("Please enter your weight in KG")
userWeight=float(input())
userBmi= userWeight/(userHeight**2)

print("your BMI is "+str(round(userBmi,1)))
```

Comment: Please provide some context on why the error happened or what you changed to make it work.